# Assembly program of adding two number

Tags: assembly, x86

I have generated below dump from a  program that only adds two numbers 
I am not able to understand logic of adding two numbers 
In the given code 6th and 7th line , according to me makes no sense , please help with two lines

```
add ecx,00001010  6th line 

and ecx,00002020 7th line
```

```
       movzx   ecx,%GWA+000000E0 : VAR1
       movzx   eax,%GWA+000000E8 : VAR2
       sal     ecx,08
       or      ecx,eax
       mov     eax,ecx
       add     ecx,00001010
       and     ecx,00002020
       jne     GLB.4
       movzx   ecx,%GWA+000000E0 : VAR1
       movzx   eax,%GWA+000000E8 : VAR2
       and     ecx,0F0F0F0F
       and     eax,0F0F0F0F
       add     ecx,eax
       add     ecx,F6F6F6F6
       mov     eax,ecx
       and     eax,60606060
       shr     eax,04
       and     ecx,0F0F0F0F
       sub     ecx,eax
       or      ecx,30303030
       add     ecx,10
       bswap   ecx
       shr     ecx,10
       mov     %GWA+0000000A,cx : TRLP+0
       jmp     GLB.5
```

Comment: @user143252 It is your job to deliver an appropriately formatted question. If you don't do that, you get downvotes.

Comment: It first adds 0x1010 to `ecx`, and then it does a bitwise AND of `ecx` with 0x2020. Is that the part you don't understand? What you actually asking here?

Comment: @CodyGray yes exactly , why this is needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two lines are checking for a "negative" sign on either of the 16 bit zoned or unpacked decimal numbers, which contain one decimal digit per byte (bcd - binary coded decimal) in the low order bits (bits 0 to 3). The sign is stored in bits 4 through 7 of the least significant byte. Looking at the last byte of zoned or unpacked decimal number, a value of 0x10, 0x50, 0x90, 0xd0 would indicate a negative number.

The code after jne GLB.4 is doing an unpacked bcd add, but then it does a byte swap, so I'm not sure what it's doing with the sum.

Can you include the Cobol data division for the two numbers, and the procedure division for the add?

```
;       using desktop calculator in hex mode
;               ecx = 002030405h      ;decimal 2345
;               eax = 002070809h      ;decimal 2789
        add     ecx,eax               ;ecx = 0040A0C0Eh
        add     ecx,0F6F6F6F6h        ;ecx = 0FB010304h  ;F6 does carries
        mov     eax,ecx               ;eax = 0FB010304h
        and     eax,060606060h        ;eax = 060000000h  ;eax = value to subtract
        shr     eax,004               ;eax = 006000000h  ; for the non carries
        and     ecx,00F0F0F0Fh        ;ecx = 00B010304h  ;clear any 'F's
        sub     ecx,eax               ;ecx = 005010304h  ;fix the non carries
                                      ;ecx = decimal 5134
```

Comment: Yup i will do , thanks for the help

Comment: I have added info @rcgldr

Comment: @user143252 - What I'm looking for is the Cobol source code for the variables VAR1 and VAR2, and the source code that shows the add.

Comment: @user143252 - the code for unpacked add is already there, first line of code at 00000200 and last line at 00000223.

Comment: @user143252 - you can use a desktop calculator in hex mode to follow the logic. Adding F6F6F6F6 produces the correct result in the bytes that generate carries (a byte sum >= 10). The rest of the code is to handle the bytes that didn't generate carries. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks a lot for gud answer